# MySQL implementation with CUDA

Tags: mysql, database, cuda

I am a senior undergrad majoring in CS. At the moment I am taking a Computer Architecture class. We need to do a project. I want to do something related to CUDA, where the performance of the computation will have a moderate increase compred to a serial implementation.

I am really interested in databases so I decided to do something related to SQL. I only have experience with MySQL and I could not find anything related to how to work with MySQL using CUDA. There is only one reseasrch I could find about SQL and it uses SQLite. I am not sure what to do and how to gather information on this subject so I decided to take your opinions.

Best

Comment: Vote to close: This question is far too vague; in fact, there is no question!

Comment: CUDA is not suitable for interacting with MySQL in any way.  A more appropriate project might be to implement a read only database of a certain kind of data and use CUDA to do searching or pattern matching.

Comment: Agree with mch, CUDA and MySQL don't really go together - If you're interested in databases and speedups maybe look at distributed databases (cassandra?)

Answer (score 7):

Just in case someone end-up in this page, the [PGStorm](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PGStrom) is a module of foreign data wrapper of **PostgreSQL** database.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look at implementation of SQL language which runs on GPU and uses CUDA.
it is open source so you can look at algorithms for joins, sorts and groupings.
Link :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/alenka/

Answer (score 1):

Really?  Google found this from NVIDIA:

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=100342

They have a guide.  Is that not suitable?  It's certainly not for the faint of heart.

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/NVIDIA_CUDA_Programming_Guide_1.1.pdf

Comment: In that forum post they advice the person to extract the data by PHP without using CUDA, so I guess that is useless. I need to use CUDA directly on the database.

Comment: @user34315: That doesn't make any sense.  At a low level, a database is just a bunch of data on a filesystem; all access to the database goes through a dedicated driver.  A GPU cannot access the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary to everyone else, while I'm not sure how, a GPU can work with MySQL... I dont know why every says it couldnt. If there is CPU workload in MySQL then whatever that CPU is doing, at some level, if someone took the time to implement it, a GPU could, for example, work on UPDATING separate rows on separate threads. Could either alloc each table to each block, or just freeform it and let the end user decide.

Or at least someone could edit the driver to speed up efficiency of communication.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that now there's a solution for querying data using `SQL` on `gpus` in `python` :

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-querying-data-using-sql-on-gpus-in-python/

I wonder if they are some other possibilities using different programming langages though.

Comment: For answer's with link(s), it is advisable  to highlight the important details or provide a summary regarding what you found in the link you provided. Because time will come that the link will be unavailable/invalid.