# does it benefit to use a GPU server for mysql database

Tags: database, gpu

I have to move my database (Mysqli) + php website  to a new server, does it make a big difference in performance  if I buy a server with GPU?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047337/mysql-implementation-with-cuda

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no version of MySQL that uses CUDA, OpenCL, or otherwise.